# ТолстовскАЯ "Война и мир"

Tags: согласование

Отрывок из статьи Проханова на сайте "Известия.ру":

*Они [современные молодые люди] уже не знали, кто такие княгиня Ольга и святой князь Владимир. Кто такие Карамзин и Ключевский. Не знали, чем кончается **толстовская** «Война и мир» и кто написал «Повесть о настоящем человеке»*.

Правильно ли здесь выбрано согласование притяжательного прилагательного с названием романа, и если нет, то какое согласование будет правильным: *толстовск**ий*** - потому что **роман** "Война и мир", или - *толстовск**ие*** - потому что в названии не только война, но и мир?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во всех отношениях неправильно. Во-первых, "толстовский" - здесь неудачное прилагательное, от фамилий на ий/ой и ский/ской лучше обозначать притяжательность родительным падежом ("ВиМ" Тостого - если только речь не идет о именах собственных: "Толстовский дом", "Толстовский Центр" - когда первое слово пишется с заглавной). Но это еще не так страшно, не буду акцентировать.

Вот образование прилагательного женского рода здесь совершенно неуместно. "ВиМ" - роман, поэтому единственный выход из взаимоисключающих требований согласования по роду и числу - мужской род. *Длинный "Война и Мир"*. Тоже не фонтан, но все лучше. Ну а нормальным является использование родового слова. ***Энциклопедический роман "Война и мир" Толстого***. Только такой вариант можно признать безупречным.

*Ну и конечно, не могу не заметить, что Проханов - крайне неудачный автор для изучения стилистики. Он и в лучшие-то свои годы был весьма косноязычным... А сейчас совсем (вот даже по этому тексту судя), совсем сдал. Или это другой Проханов, не Александр Андреевич?*

*О "святом князе Владимире" до известных событий почти и не вспоминали в школе. А за пределами школы вспоминали не иначе как о садисте, развратнике и насильнике. А вон оно как вылилось. Россия страна с непредсказуемым прошлым.*

Comment: "Или это другой Проханов, не Александр Андреевич?" - Тот самый Проханов :)